# Java QName prefix not working

Tags: java, xml-namespaces

My question is quite simple.
I'm adding a header to a SOAP request that needs to have a namespace prefix. As such I'm using

```
QName(String namespaceURI,
             String localPart,
             String prefix)
```

The problem is that although I set the prefix nothing is added, i.e:

```
new QName("http://lit.com/schemas/Bobsled", "bob:sessionId")
```

I get `<bob:sessionId xmlns="http://lit.com/schemas/Bobsled">`

And with the prefix:

```
new QName("http://lit.com/schemas/Bobsled", "bob:sessionId","bob")
```

I get exactly the same thing, when it should be:

```
<bob:sessionId xmlns:bob="http://lit.com/schemas/Bobsled">
```

...it seems like the prefix in the constructor isn't doing anything!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

prefix for qname is third parameter in `QName` constructor

```
new QName("http://lit.com/schemas/Bobsled", "sessionId","bob")
```